# Pressure Sensor-MPX10DP with amplifier and Arduino UNO - output to kPa

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, pressure

I'm working with an Arduino UNO. I'm trying to use this Sensor to obtain the pressure in kPa. I'm using a `tl084cn` to amplifier the signal. But I don't know what values I'm getting and what to do with them.

Not applying  pressure prints `0`, if I apply air pressure it's goes up to `800-900` as max. What mean this values?

What is the maximum pressure that I should get? 10 kPa? I don't understand that very well. Because the data sheet says:

> Maximum Pressure (P1 > P2) PMAX 75 kPa

I can understand what is the differences between Max. Pressure and Max. Differential Pressure.

Comment: Your previous question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40234/how-to-connect-a-pressure-sensor-mpx10dp-to-an-arduino The TL084 is not an instrumentation amplifier. The MPX10DP can measure from 0 to 10 kPa differential pressure and it breaks at 75 kPa differential pressure. The sensor output has a offset of 20mV and a range of 35mV. When no pressure is applied, you measure the offset.

Comment: @Jot So, I can't use the TL084 to amplify the output?

Comment: You can amplify the signal with a TL084, but depending on the circuit the impedance of the circuit could influence the bridge output of the sensor. Measuring the exact pressure would be disturbed. The output impedance of the sensor is about 1 kΩ. Are you really determined to get into more and more trouble instead of buying a MPX5010 ? With a MPX5010 all your troubles are gone at once.

Comment: @Jot, the problem is that in my country there is no place to buy a MPX5010, that's why I was trying to accomplish it with this sensor from my college laboratory.

Comment: And what about a INA125 or similar instrumentation amplifier ? Those are made for wheatstone sensors. Or what about an Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Mega 2560 ? Those have internal differential mode with a gain, that is somewhat similar to a instrumentation amplifier.